# Emma report executable under ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, emma

I'm trying to report coverage data from command line in linux ubuntu. I use openjdk 6, and emma.jar (v 2.0.5312) is located (moved by me) /usr/bin (and this path is also in the path variable). 
If I run the command

```
java emma report -r xml -Dreport.xml.out.file=coverage.xml -Dreport.depth=all -in coverage.em -in coverage.ec
```

I get:

```
emmarun usage: emmarun [options] class [args...] | -jar [options] jarfile [args...],
where options include:
[...omissis, all the emmarun command options]
[EMMA v2.0, build 5312]
```

but I don't want to run emmarun, just report emma coverage files. Where am I wrong? Is the executable of emma right?